# Serif \text in formulas in Beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts

In my Beamer presentation, I specify the Palatino font as a math font.
However, in the formulas I can see that a sans-serif font is used inside `\text` macros.

I use `pdflatex` for compilation.

How to force `\text` macros produce serif text?

Minimal Working Example (MWE):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Optimization problem}
We arrive at the optimization problem
\begin{align}
    &\argmin_{\theta} \quad \ \ 
        \sum_{i=1}^N \big[u_i - u_{\text{NN}}(x_i, t_i; \theta)\big]^2  \\
    &\text{subject to } \ \ u_{\text{NN}, t}  + N(u_\text{NN}) = 0
\end{align}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the wrong usage of `\text` anyways. Remember that`\text` switches to the text font. Use mathrm instead.

Comment: Off-topic:  the package  `beamer` doesn't exist. In your code remove line `\usepackage{beamer}`.

Comment: @daleif, thanks, I have managed to solve the problem by using `\textrm` instead of `\text`.

Comment: @Zarko, thank you, it was wrong line, deleted it.

Comment: @DmitryKabanov, not `\textrm` but `\mathrm`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explain @daleif in his comment, use of `\text` is switch between fonts used in math environments and in a text. Correct way in your case (and all similar cases) is to use `\mathrm` command (I also suggest to use `alignat` environment instead of `align`, code is slightly simpler):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Optimization problem}
We arrive at the optimization problem
\begin{alignat}{3}
    &\argmin_{\theta} 
    &\quad  &   \sum_{i=1}^N \big[u_i - u_{\mathrm{NN}}(x_i, t_i; \theta)\big]^2  \\
    &\text{subject to} 
    &       &   u_{\mathrm{NN}, t}  + N(u_\mathrm{NN}) = 0
\end{alignat}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note: *redefining basic command from `amsmath` packages is dangerous*.  Never do this!

[image]

Comment: One comment: to enforce serif font on "subject to", one can use `\textrm` macro in formulas. `\mathrm` swallows spaces in the text.

Comment: @DmitryKabanov, "subject to" is ordinary text (in equation), so the use of the `\text{...}` is correct in this case. Similarly you will have ordinary text at using `\intertext{...}`or `\shortintertext{...}` for  text between multi line equation.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE on 28 July 2019**: redefining `\text` macro can be dangerous as it is one of the basic macros. This was is not recommended, therefore.

To ensure serif text font in math formulas, the command `\textrm` should be used, as the command `\text` matches normal text, which in Beamer by default is sans serif.

Alternatively, one can renew command `\text` such that it becomes an alias for `\textrm`:

```
\renewcommand{\text}[1]{\textrm{#1}}
```

Comment: Don't do this!It is very dangerous to redefine basic `latex` commands! Please consider @daleif comment and stay on safe side of using `latex`. Replacing `\text` with `\mathrm` is not big deal fore an editor.